# How to check multiple file sizes before submit?

Tags: jquery

I try to prevent to upload file before submit when file size is bigger than 2 MB

with one input everything works fine but with multiple inputs something goes wrong

anybody can help me ?

this is my fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AKZ2f/)

```
$('#zzz').submit(function() {
    var valid_form = true;

    var thumb1_size = $('#1')[0].files[0].size;
    if (thumb1_size > 2097152) {
        $('.error').html(thumb1_size);
        valid_form = false;
        alert(valid_form)
    }
})
```

if i change on

```
    $('#zzz').submit(function() {
    var valid_form = true;

    var thumb1_size = $('#1')[0].files[0].size;
    var thumb2_size = $('#2')[0].files[0].size;
    if (thumb1_size > 2097152 || thumb2_size > 2097152 ) {
        $('.error').html(thumb1_size);
        valid_form = false;
        alert(valid_form)
    }
})
```

the form is submitting even valid_form is returning false

Comment: Can you elaborate "something goes wrong"? Also, right now you're only checking the size of one input file. Is that what you want?

Comment: I added answer, explained why form is submitting and whats wrong with your code (previous and this versions)

Comment: you have to use : `event.preventDefault();` to prevent form from submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong? You need to calculate and handle size of each input field. Also, you send form anyway. You have to prevent it by [`prevenDefault` function](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Use this:

```
$('#zzz').submit(function (event) {  
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("input").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            var name = this.files[0].name;
            var size = this.files[0].size;
            if(size > 2097152) {
                alert('error');
                $('.error').append("<p>Size of file \""+name+"\" is wrong: "+size+"</p>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AKZ2f/42/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for response..it works fine - but how change this to those inputs will work separately. I mean if i leve one input empty ? It dont work when i firstly try upload second file.

Comment: Do you need to prevent form from submitting only if it has errors?

Comment: @wiecman I had updated my answer. Do you need to prevent form from submitting only if it has errors?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I see that you also used `event.preventDefault();` on the `each` loop, and inside an `if` !!!!

Comment: @wiecman so explain please: do you need to send form without any files?

Comment: @mr "more correct"? :P My answer helped OP, code in my asnwer did what OP needs. "More correct?" :) Choose with OP what answer is correct, I am done there. _Simple advice: don't chase reputation, you just need some time to gain it. Sure if you will be more friendly :)_

Comment: also it is a bad practice to downvote good answers!
and I mean **more correct** , because your code does prevent submission always even if the correct files have been uploaded. 
i don't know how the OP give you the answer.

Comment: @wiecman this code prevent the submission if the files have been uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

this will show error when some files are not uploaded , and also it will check the size.

**see it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/dTNh3/1/)**

```
$('#zzz').submit(function (event) {
     $('.error').html('');
     var valid_form = true;
     var files = $('input[type=file]');
     for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].files[0] != null){
             var fileSize = files[i].files[0].size;
             if (fileSize > 2097152) {
                 valid_form = false;
                 $('.error').append("<p>File #" + (i + 1).toString() + " is too large</p>");
             }
         }else{
             valid_form = false;
             $('.error').append("<p>File #" + (i + 1).toString() + " is not there!</p>");
         }
     }
     if(!valid_form)event.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
});
```

Comment: What is event? You didn't pass this variable anywhere. Also, why you prevent form from submitting in loop and in if condition?

Comment: it is not necessarily to provide the "event" as a parameter, but I have updated the answer,
also we want to prevent the submission only when the error occur.
please remove your downvote as I am trying to help here not to receive downvotes on correct answers (you can check the fiddle).